# Ruby - Having trouble with simple ToDo list program with classes and methods

Tags: ruby

I want to make a small and simple todo list program. I've been blank for a couple hours on this. Here's the instruuctions:

````
> # Write a program that keeps a list of todos. It should:
> # * Have two classes:
> #   * `Todo`
> #     * Has two methods:
> #       * `initialize`: Creates a new todo object. Takes a string as a
> #         parameter and stores it on the todo object.
> 
> #       * `text`: Takes no parameters. Returns the string that was
> #         stored when the todo object was created.
> 
>  
> #   * `TodoList`
> #     * Has three methods:
> #       * `initialize`: Creates a new todo list object. Takes no parameters.
> 
> #       * `add`: Takes a todo object as a parameter.  Stores it on the
> #         todo list object.
> 
> #       * `print`: Takes no parameters.  Creates a string of all the
> #         stored todos, one per line.  Each line should start with a
> #         `* `.  `puts`es the string.
> 
> #         * e.g.
> #           ```
> #           * get milk
> #           * get the papers
> #           ```
````

Here is my attempt at the code for the program:

```
class Todo
  def initialize(todo)
    @todo = todo
  end

  def text
    @todo
  end
end
class TodoList
  def initialize
    @todo_list = []
  end

  def add(todo)
    @todo_list << Todo.new(todo)
  end

  def print
    @todo_list.each do |x|
      puts "* #{x}"
    end
  end
end
```

I know I'm missing something here but I cant seem to see what.. When I test it I pass all of the tests except for 2, both of the failed tests concern the print method which is described in the TodoList class.

Comment: You have an error in your print method. It should be puts "* #{x.text}"

Comment: it's really helpful when you write code, to run it and see the output ... in this case you would clearly see that the puts statement does not output the text

Comment: Hint: Make a `to_s` method for `Todo` that converts it to a well-formatted string.

Comment: @chemical , thank you but no this still does not fix the issue i am having

Comment: in fact, the 3 above suggestions ars still returning me the same print error messages

Comment: "I test it I pass all of the tests except for 2". Which tests are these and what do they say would be a big help.

Answer (score 2):

A bit of a break down for you on what is happening.

```
class Todo
  def initialize(todo)
    @todo = todo   # This sets your instance variable @todo to whatever you passing, you will probably want to add a check to make sure you only accept strings
  end

  def text
    @todo  # The text method is returning whatever the @todo variable is, in this case since you are passing a string, it is returning a string
  end
end

class TodoList
  def initialize
    @todo_list = []  # When you are initializing your TodoList you are creating an array called @todo_list
  end

  def add(todo)
    @todo_list << Todo.new(todo) # When you call this method you are adding a new instance of your Todo class
  end

  def print
    # Here you are iterating through your array @todo_list, which we established earlier is an array of your Todo Class variables
    @todo_list.each do |x| # Pro tip, try to stay away from using names like 'x' or 'y' use more descriptive names
      # Your 'x' variable here is one of your Todo classes instances
      puts "* #{x.text}" # As defined in your Todo class, you will need to call the text method to retrieve the text you stored in your class
    end
  end
end

list = TodoList.new  # Here we create a new instance of your TodoList class

list.add('Buy Pizza') # Here we can add items onto your todo list
list.add('Buy Pie')
list.add('Buy Potato')
list.print  # This is how you will print all the items you added to your TodoList
```

This will return

```
* Buy Pizza
* Buy Pie
* Buy Potato
```